# VBA Word - extract Excel files fast

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, extract

I want to extract several embedded Excel files in a Word document. I use this code which works:

```
Sub ExtractExcel()
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim ISh As InlineShape
    Dim Path As String: Path = "C:\tmp\"
    Dim Excel As Boolean: Excel = False

    For Each ISh In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If ISh.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            If InStr(LCase(ISh.OLEFormat.ProgID), "excel") > 0 Then
                ISh.OLEFormat.Activate
                If Not Excel Then Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
                Excel = True
                If Dir(Path & ISh.OLEFormat.IconLabel) <> "" Then Kill Path & ISh.OLEFormat.IconLabel
                ExcelApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs Path & ISh.OLEFormat.IconLabel
                ExcelApp.Workbooks(1).Close
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Excel Then ExcelApp.Quit
    
End Sub
```

This procedure takes time because an Excel application is opened and it flashes for each file. Is there a way to speed up the extraction?

1. I tried to unzip the Word document and copy the Excel file from `word/embeddings` but the Excel file does not open.
2. I also tried to convert with `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape ClassType:="Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12" …` the ole objects to a binary Excel format, I cut the ole-header from the unzipped files `word/embeddings/oleObjectN.bin` and renamed them properly. But again, the Excel files don’t open:

Is there is any better (optimized) way?

Comment: Don't close the workbook(s) until after you've saved all of them and exited the loop. That should speed it up.